# How to use different input and output device as a single device on fedora 34

Tags: fedora, audio, alsamixer

I want to use a speaker as my output and a separate microphone for my input. The issue is when I do this, I get echo as expected. I need to create a virtual audio device that has input and output. I cant find anything like that. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Unless you place your speaker somewhere where the microphone doesn't pick it up, you'll always get feedback ("echo"). There are echo cancellation plugins e.g. for Pulseaudio, but don't know how well they work. Basically all applications program can choose output from a different device than input. Do you have a concrete application where this doesn't work, and where you'd need to create a virtual audio device? If not, then a virtual device is not what you need.

Comment: I want to have a setup where my guests can listen through the speakers, and I was planning on having a microphone in the middle to pick up their Audio when they speak. I read that Anc work by inverting the outside noise so I was hoping if there was a way to apply a the filter that is an invert of the Audio playing through the speakers or something.

Comment: That's basically echo cancellation, except you need to add some delay to make it work, and ideally you want to calculate the delay automatically. Google "pulseaudio echo cancellation".

Comment: The direct answer to the question as asked is "No. No one can help you." What you want is not a virtual device that separates input and output--you already have input and output to separate devices, "speakers" and "microphone", and you cannot combine them: It makes no sense to send an audio signal _to_ a microphone or try to pick up sound _from_ a speaker. (These are possible with specialized circuits and signal processing, but in general, it makes no sense.) What you really want is what @dirkt suggested, "echo cancellation" applied to the microphone signal.